# Space in front of the output in assembly

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86-64, masm

I'm writing an assembly (x64) program that uses 3 MACROS (mGetHandles, mWriteFile, mReadFile). I suppose to produce the following output (user input in **boldface**):

What is your name? **John Smith**
What is your address? **54321 Main St., La Mesa**
Nice to meet you, 
John Smith
54321 Main St., La Mesa

This is my code:

```
CONSOLE     equ     -11
KEYBOARD    equ     -10

CR          equ         0dh
LF          equ         0ah

extern GetStdHandle:    PROTO
extern WriteFile:       PROTO
extern ReadFile:        PROTO
extrn ExitProcess:      PROTO

.data
prompt1     byte    'What is your name? '
prompt2     byte    'What is your adress? '
hello       byte    'Nice to meet you, ', CR, LF 
myname      byte    40 dup(' '), CR, LF, 0
myadress    byte    40 dup(' ')
crlf        byte    CR, LF, 0       ;used to get a new line

.data?
stdin       qword   ?   ;handle to console standard in
stdout      qword   ?   ;handle to console standard out
numWrite    qword   ?   ;number bytes actually written
numRead     qword   ?   ;number bytes actually read

mGetStdHandle   MACRO

                ;Get handle ID to console window
                mov rcx, CONSOLE            ;subsystem:console
                call GetStdHandle           ;handle in rax
                mov stdout, rax             ;save out handle
                mov rcx, KEYBOARD           ;keyboard code
                call GetStdHandle           ;handle in rax
                mov stdin, rax              ;save in handle


ENDM

mWriteFile      MACRO
                ;Display message on console window
                mov rcx, stdout             ;parm1 = console handle
                lea rdx, prompt1            ;parm2 = ascii message
                mov r8, lengthof prompt1    ;# bytes to display (write)
                lea r9, numWrite            ;& to store #bytes written
                call WriteFile              ;display message

                ;Read ASCII from the keyboard
                mov rcx, offset crlf        ;cr, lf
                mov rcx, stdin              ;parm1 = keyboard handle
                lea rdx, myname             ;parm1 = ascii buffer
                mov r8, lengthof myname     ;# bytes of read
                lea r9, numRead             ;& to store #bytes actually read
                call ReadFile               ;get keystrokes

                ;Display message on console window
                mov rcx, stdout             ;parm1 = console handle
                lea rdx, prompt2            ;parm2 = ascii message
                mov r8, lengthof prompt2    ;# bytes to display (write)
                lea r9, numWrite            ;& to store #bytes written
                call WriteFile              ;display message


                ;Read ASCII from the keyboard
                mov rcx, offset crlf        ;cr, lf
                mov rcx, stdin              ;parm1 = keyboard handle
                lea rdx, myadress           ;parm1 = ascii buffer
                mov r8, lengthof myadress   ;# bytes of read
                lea r9, numRead             ;& to store #bytes actually read
                call ReadFile               ;get keystrokes


ENDM

mReadFile       MACRO
                mov rcx, stdout             ;parm1 = console handle
                lea rdx, hello              ;parm2 = ascii message
                mov r8, lengthof hello      ;# bytes to display (write)
                add r8, numRead             ;& to store #bytes actually read
                sub r8, 2
                lea r9, numWrite            ;& to store #bytes written
                call WriteFile              ;display message    

                mov rcx, stdout             ;parm1 = console handle
                lea rdx, myadress           ;parm2 = ascii message
                mov r8, lengthof myadress   ;# bytes to display (write)
                add r8, numRead             ;& to store #bytes actually read
                sub r8, 2
                lea r9, numWrite            ;& to store #bytes written
                call WriteFile              ;display message
ENDM

mBye            MACRO       retcode
                mov  rcx, retcode
                callExitProcess
ENDM

.code
mainCRTStartup  PROC

                mGetStdHandle
                mWriteFile
                mReadFile
                call ExitProcess

mainCRTStartup  ENDP
END
```

The output I get is("___" represents empty space):
Nice to meet you,
John Smith
__________54321 Main St., La Mesa
Why is there space before "54321 Main St., La Mesa"?

Comment: For some reason you add `numRead` to the `lengthof` which doesn't make sense to me. Also, you overwrite `numRead` because you use it for both of your inputs. The first space is likely not a space at all, but the trailing `0` from the `hello` which you don't need since you use explicit length and not zero termination.

Comment: Okay, you're right the 0 is tailing that fixes the Name space.

Comment: How do I fix the space for the street name?

Comment: The end-of-line character sequence in Windows is CR/LF, not LF/CR. The order matters.

Comment: lol, yeah sorry I changed it.

Comment: You fix the other spaces by using the `numRead` properly. You are printing too many characters from the name hence you are printing the trailing spaces left in the buffer.